# How to filter data with hidden data?

Tags: klipfolio

In my klipfolio data source I have a field version-name. The data in there is numeric and alpha. I only want to see the numeric version. So I created a hidden data which will evaluate to true when the first digit is numeric (this rule is valid in my case):

```
IN( LEFT( @/issues/fields/fixVersions/name;, 1), ARRAY( 0, CUMULATIVE(REPEAT(1,9))))
```

but the hidden data does not change my output? Do I need to apply this somewhere to get the current result filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a hidden data slot to act as a filter, right click on the hidden data slot -> Filter... then in the Members tab, select "True". This will filter out all the records that do not have a digit as the first value in the string.